# What is the behavior of a UFW rule that does not specify a protocol?

Tags: ufw, protocol

This is such a basic question I was surprised I couldn't find the answer, but here we are.

With the following rule:

`22    ALLOW    192.168.1.0/24`

Are all protocols allowed or is TCP assumed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is directly answered in [the manpage](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/kinetic/en/man8/ufw.8.html):

```
Users  can  specify rules using either a simple syntax or a full syntax. The simple syntax
only specifies the port and optionally the protocol to be allowed or denied on the host.

[...]

Example rules using the simple syntax:

  ufw allow 53

This  rule  will  allow  tcp  and  udp  port  53 to any address on this host. To specify a
protocol, append '/protocol' to the port. For example:

  ufw allow 25/tcp

This will allow tcp port 25 to any address on this host.
```